# Не работает transition для плавной анимации

Tags: javascript, html, css

В этом коде реализовано удаление и создание элементов как `checkbox`. И тут возникла проблема с анимацией: при клике на галочку слово должно было вычёркиваться с плавной анимацией, но что-то не так.  Закреплю полный код, чтобы было понятнее.

```js
const inpText = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]')
const btn = document.querySelector('.c')
const wrappper = document.querySelector('.container')
const resept = document.querySelector('.r')

const tasks = [{
    id: 1,
    isFinished: false,
    taskName: 'Создать задачу'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    isFinished: false,
    taskName: 'Выполнить задание'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    isFinished: false,
    taskName: 'Проснуться утром'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    isFinished: false,
    taskName: 'Приготовить завтрак'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    isFinished: false,
    taskName: 'Поцеловать маму'
  },
]

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const newTask = {
    id: tasks.length + 1,
    isFinished: false,
    taskName: inpText.value,
  }
  tasks.unshift(newTask)
  renderTasks(tasks)
})

const renderTasks = (arr) => {
  wrappper.innerHTML = ''
  arr.forEach(task => {
    const taskDiv = document.createElement('div')
    taskDiv.className = 'task'
    const label = document.createElement('label')
    const chbox = document.createElement('input')
    chbox.type = 'checkbox'
    chbox.checked = task.isFinished

    const spanName = document.createElement('span')
    spanName.innerText = task.taskName
    const btnRemove = document.createElement('button')
    btnRemove.classList.toggle('btnRemove')
    btnRemove.innerHTML = 'x'
    label.append(chbox, spanName, btnRemove)

    btnRemove.addEventListener('click', () => {
      const newArr = arr.filter((item) => item.id !== task.id)
      renderTasks(newArr)
    })

    taskDiv.append(label)
    wrappper.append(taskDiv)

    chbox.addEventListener('change', () => {
      if (chbox.checked) {
        spanName.classList.add('active')
      } else {
        spanName.classList.remove('active')
      }
    })
  })
}

renderTasks(tasks)
```

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

span.active {
  margin-top: 70px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 1s;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.task {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

span.active::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #9b7ede;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 50%;
}

.btnRemove {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 8px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  color: #9b7ede;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: relative;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: #9b7ede;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.d {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.active {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  transition: text-decoration 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="d">
  <input type="text">
  <button class="c">create</button>
  <button class="r">resept all</button>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="task">
      <label>
        <!-- <input type="checkbox">
        <span>Создать задачу</span> -->
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы transition сработал - он должен стоять у элемента, который изменяется.
В данном случае это `span::before`. Также этот элемент должен присутствовать в DOM, следовательно нужно перенести все исходные стили из `span.active` в `span::before`, за исключением конечной ширины в 100%, исходную ширину можно выставить в `0`.

```js
const inpText = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]')
const btn = document.querySelector('.c')
const wrappper = document.querySelector('.container')
const resept = document.querySelector('.r')

const tasks = [{
    id: 1,
    isFinished: false,
    taskName: 'Создать задачу'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    isFinished: false,
    taskName: 'Выполнить задание'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    isFinished: false,
    taskName: 'Проснуться утром'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    isFinished: false,
    taskName: 'Приготовить завтрак'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    isFinished: false,
    taskName: 'Поцеловать маму'
  },
]

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const newTask = {
    id: tasks.length + 1,
    isFinished: false,
    taskName: inpText.value,
  }
  tasks.unshift(newTask)
  renderTasks(tasks)
})

const renderTasks = (arr) => {
  wrappper.innerHTML = ''
  arr.forEach(task => {
    const taskDiv = document.createElement('div')
    taskDiv.className = 'task'
    const label = document.createElement('label')
    const chbox = document.createElement('input')
    chbox.type = 'checkbox'
    chbox.checked = task.isFinished

    const spanName = document.createElement('span')
    spanName.innerText = task.taskName
    const btnRemove = document.createElement('button')
    btnRemove.classList.toggle('btnRemove')
    btnRemove.innerHTML = 'x'
    label.append(chbox, spanName, btnRemove)

    btnRemove.addEventListener('click', () => {
      const newArr = arr.filter((item) => item.id !== task.id)
      renderTasks(newArr)
    })

    taskDiv.append(label)
    wrappper.append(taskDiv)

    chbox.addEventListener('change', () => {
      if (chbox.checked) {
        spanName.classList.add('active')
        spanName.offsetHeight;
      } else {
        spanName.classList.remove('active')
      }
    })
  })
}

renderTasks(tasks)
```

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

span {
  position: relative;
}

.task {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

span::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #9b7ede;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 50%;
  transition: width 1s;
}

span.active::before {
  width: 100%;
}

.btnRemove {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 8px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  color: #9b7ede;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: relative;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: #9b7ede;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.d {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="d">
  <input type="text">
  <button class="c">create</button>
  <button class="r">resept all</button>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="task">
      <label>
        <!-- <input type="checkbox">
        <span>Создать задачу</span> -->
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

В CSS анимировать свойство `text-decoration: line-through;` **невозможно**. Но можно написать свою простенькую анимацию вычеркивания.

```js
const inpText = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]')
const btn = document.querySelector('.c')
const wrappper = document.querySelector('.container')
const resept = document.querySelector('.r')

const tasks = [{
    id: 1,
    isFinished: false,
    taskName: 'Создать задачу'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    isFinished: false,
    taskName: 'Выполнить задание'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    isFinished: false,
    taskName: 'Проснуться утром'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    isFinished: false,
    taskName: 'Приготовить завтрак'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    isFinished: false,
    taskName: 'Поцеловать маму'
  },
]

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const newTask = {
    id: tasks.length + 1,
    isFinished: false,
    taskName: inpText.value,
  }
  tasks.unshift(newTask)
  renderTasks(tasks)
})

const renderTasks = (arr) => {
  wrappper.innerHTML = ''
  arr.forEach(task => {
    const taskDiv = document.createElement('div')
    taskDiv.className = 'task'
    const label = document.createElement('label')
    const chbox = document.createElement('input')
    chbox.type = 'checkbox'
    chbox.checked = task.isFinished

    const spanName = document.createElement('span')
    spanName.innerText = task.taskName
    const btnRemove = document.createElement('button')
    btnRemove.classList.toggle('btnRemove')
    btnRemove.innerHTML = 'x'
    label.append(chbox, spanName, btnRemove)

    btnRemove.addEventListener('click', () => {
      const newArr = arr.filter((item) => item.id !== task.id)
      renderTasks(newArr)
    })

    taskDiv.append(label)
    wrappper.append(taskDiv)

    chbox.addEventListener('change', () => {
      if (chbox.checked) {
        spanName.classList.add('active')
      } else {
        spanName.classList.remove('active')
      }
    })
  })
}

renderTasks(tasks)
```

```css
/* анимация вычеркивания */
@keyframes done {
  from {
    width: 0%;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

span.active {
  margin-top: 70px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 1s;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.task {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

span.active::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #9b7ede;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 50%;

  /* применим анимацию */
  animation: done 0.3s ease-in-out forwards;
}

.btnRemove {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 8px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  color: #9b7ede;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: relative;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: #9b7ede;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.d {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="d">
  <input type="text">
  <button class="c">create</button>
  <button class="r">resept all</button>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="task">
      <label>
        <!-- <input type="checkbox">
        <span>Создать задачу</span> -->
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```